# Changing size of a panel

Tags: java, user-interface, grid-layout, panels

Soo I'm trying to make two panels and I wanted the top panel to be at least 2/3 of the window. I used GridLayout and it splits it in half, and I want to make it soo that the top is a little bit bigger. Is there another Layout I should consider instead of GridLayout?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `javax.swing.JSplitPane` like:

```
JSplitPane spt = new JSplitPane();
spt.setDividerSize(12);
spt.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
spt.setRightComponent(imagePanel1);
spt.setLeftComponent(imagePanel2);
spt.setDividerLocation(0.8);
```

And adjust the values for your necessity.

Comment: Thank you soo much! Just what I was looking for

Comment: @user2779767, `Just what I was looking for` - take a look at the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html).  If has sections on all Swing components and layout managers so you can learn about Swing functionality. Also, you may want to use the setTopComponent(...) and setBottomComponent(...) methods since that would be more appropriate for a vertical split.